# (Overleaf) Is it possible to output image (e.g. PNG file) instead of PDF?

Tags: overleaf

I found a tutorial on [converting a PDF to SVG](https://dav.jianguoyun.com/dav/), but this method seems to only work on local devices. I wonder if it is possible to output images from LaTeX using online compilers like Overleaf.

Comment: There is an article on doing this for PNG at https://www.overleaf.com/blog/613-tip-of-the-week-how-to-convert-typeset-pdf-pages-into-raster-image-formats

Comment: Hi David, I find your answer very useful for my question. Thank you so much!